# Ускорить выборку в базу

Tags: php, sql

```
     $sql = "SELECT MIN(o.date_added) AS date_start, MAX(o.date_added) AS date_end, COUNT(*) AS orders , 
            SUM((SELECT SUM(op.quantity) FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id GROUP BY op.order_id)) AS products , 
            SUM((SELECT SUM(ot.value) FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'tax' GROUP BY ot.order_id)) AS tax,
            SUM(o.total) AS `total` FROM `".DB_PREFIX."order` o";

    if (!empty($data['filter_order_status_id'])) {
        $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_order_status_id'] . "'";
    } else {
        $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id > '0'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_date_start'])) {
        $sql .= " AND DATE(o.date_added) >= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_start']) . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_date_end'])) {
        $sql .= " AND DATE(o.date_added) <= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_end']) . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_group'])) {
        $group = $data['filter_group'];
    } else {
        $group = 'week';
    }

    switch($group) {
        case 'day';
            $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added), MONTH(o.date_added), DAY(o.date_added)";
            break;
        default:
        case 'week':
            $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added), WEEK(o.date_added)";
            break;
        case 'month':
            $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added), MONTH(o.date_added)";
            break;
        case 'year':
            $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added)";
            break;
    }

    $sql .= " ORDER BY o.date_added DESC";

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Когда нагрузка на сайт не большая загружается за 8.62 s когда нагрузка большая то загружается долго , как можно ускорить запрос?

Comment: Для начала избавится от применения любых функций к колонкам таблицы в части where. т.е. вместо `DATE(o.date_added)` использовать `o.date_added >= X` и `o.date_added < X+interval 1 day` (строго меньше следующего дня как раз до 23:59:59 текущего дня). После этого смотреть планы выполнения запроса (с помощью explain) и на основе них сделать недостающие индексы, например по тому же полю  date_added, если его еще нет. В любом случае ответить на ваш порос не видя полную структуру БД, знания количества записей в них всего и по каждому условию отбора и не видя explain невозможно

Comment: Вот запрос который тормозит ` SUM((SELECT SUM(op.quantity) FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id GROUP BY op.order_id)) AS products ,`  если его убрать то все нормально, может много записей 74148

Comment: повторяю - без explain говорить в принципе не о чем, только он показывает как именно БД выполняет запрос

Comment: Добрый день. С какой целью вы производите двойное суммирование? К примеру этот select `"SELECT SUM(op.quantity) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id"`будет делать то же самое, что и ваш `"SUM((SELECT SUM(op.quantity) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id GROUP BY op.order_id))" ` только без группировки и дополнительного суммирования.